# Get value from selected country language list

Tags: jquery

i have 2 select box . 1st one is country selection. If i selected the country i get the specific country selected option value.

Example if i am choose the france country display the france language list only in select box. other select box disable. i want to get the value of second select box selected option.

Please help me friends

```
    <div class="country-selection">
    <select id="country" > 
        <option value="USA">United States of America</option>
        <option value="united-kingdom" >United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="spain">Spain</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="lan-selection">
        <div class="united-states-selected USA language-selection" id="united-states-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection" >    
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select >
        </div>
        <div class="united-kingdom-selected language-selection" id="united-kingdom-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection">
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="france-selected language-selection" id="france-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection">
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div  class="german-selected language-selection" id="german-selected">
        <select  class="lan-selection"   >
                <option class="en-de" value="english">English</option>
                <option value="German">German</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="spain-selected language-selection" id="spain-selected">
        <select  class="lan-selection" >
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>

        </select>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can bind a change event to country select box and on selecting country hide all language select box first and then show concerned select box.

You should follow same naming convention for all languages `div` id, so I think id of languages select div same as 'countryOptionValue-selected'. This will help us to identify the language `div` for selected country. I did correction for `USA` and `Germany` -

```
<div class="country-selection">
    <select id="country" > 
        <option value="USA">United States of America</option>
        <option value="united-kingdom" >United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="spain">Spain</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="lan-selection">
        <div class="united-states-selected USA language-selection" id="USA-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection" >    
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select >
        </div>
        <div class="united-kingdom-selected language-selection" id="united-kingdom-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection">
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="france-selected language-selection" id="france-selected">
        <select class="lan-selection">
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div  class="germany-selected language-selection" id="germany-selected">
        <select  class="lan-selection"   >
                <option class="en-de" value="english">English</option>
                <option value="German">German</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="spain-selected language-selection" id="spain-selected">
        <select  class="lan-selection" >
                <option value="english">English</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
                <option value="OtherLan">Others</option>

        </select>
        </div>

    </div>
```

jQuery -

```
$(function(){
  //initially hide all languages but the defualt selected  
  $('div.language-selection').hide();
  $('#'+$('#country').val()+'-selected').show();

  $('#country').on('change',function(){
      var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
      $('div.language-selection').hide();//hide all languages
      $('#'+selectedCountry+'-selected').show();//show selected languages
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46nLhwkc/2/)**